# Optimization techniques for select query on single table with ~2.25M rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

I have a MySQL table running on the InnoDB engine called `squares` that has roughly 2,250,000 rows with the following table structure:

```
`squares` (
   `square_id` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `ref_coord_lat` double(8,6) NOT NULL,
   `ref_coord_long` double(9,6) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`square_id`),
   KEY `ref_coord_lat` (`ref_coord_lat`),
   KEY `ref_coord_long` (`ref_coord_long`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The first column `square_id` holds a simple incrementing value from 0 - 2.25M, while `ref_coord_lat` & `ref_coord_long` hold a set of latitude and longitude coordinates in decimal degrees for a point, respectively.

This is a read-only table. No additional rows will be added, and the only query which needs to be run against it is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `squares` WHERE 
  `ref_coord_lat` BETWEEN :southLat AND :northLat AND 
  `ref_coord_long` BETWEEN :westLong AND :eastLong
```

...where the values following the colons are PHP PDO placeholders. Essentially, the goal of this query is to fetch all coordinate points in the table that are currently in the viewport of a Google Maps window which is bounded by the 4 coordinates in the query.

I've limited the zoom level where this query is run with the Google Maps API, so that the maximum amount of rows that can be fetched is **~5600**. As the zoom level increases, the resultant fetch total decreases significantly.

Running such an example query directly in PHPMyAdmin takes 1.40-1.45 seconds. This is far too long. I'm already running standard indices on `ref_coord_lat` and `ref_coord_long` which brought the query time down from ~5 seconds, but this is still much too large for a map where an end user expects a timely response.

My question is simply: How can I further optimize this table/query to increase the speed at which results are fetched?

Comment: Did you tried to create index by long and lat?

Comment: "I'm already running standard indices on ref_coord_lat and ref_coord_long which brought the query time down from ~5 seconds"

Comment: I mean index by (long, lat) - i.e. index on two columns

Comment: Will the data fit into memory? Buy more RAM for your web server & use SQL to seed a static cache @ startup. If you need it to be lightning fast, get rid of the network trip to SQL for each request.

Comment: Check the size of InnoDB variable called `innodb_buffer_pool`. If it's 8 megabytes, that means you're running a default config, which makes MySQL run like a snail. Increase the buffer pool and you'll have it run fast.

Comment: Great self answer! Can you post your final query to explain how you use the coordinate column? Thanks.

Comment: @Thibault : Just updated my answer above, hopefully it's more clear regarding what queries I use. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating compound index on `(lat, long)` should help a lot.

However, right solution is to take a look at [MySQL spatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html). Spatial support was specifically created to deal with two-dimensional data and queries against such data. If you create appropriate spatial indexes, your typical query performance should easily exceed performance of compound index on `(lat, long)`.

Comment: A compound index didn't end up helping (well, I got comparable performance for a reduction in index size). But you are right about MySQL spatial extensions. I've switched (see my own answer) and I've seen a drastic increase in query speed.

Answer (score 3):

Your structure seems quite OK.
2,25M rows in not that much. Your rows are small, and the comparison you do are only on double values. It should be faster.

Try to run `ANALYZE`, `OPTIMIZE`, `CHECK`, `REPAIR` commands on your table to make sure your indexes are correctly constructed.

Once this is done, you should try investigate deeper in the system.
What is slowing down the query ? It can be :

- disk I/O
- memory limit (try tuning your my.cnf, see excellent http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/ )
- CPU (seems improbable)
- network issues

Use monitoring to have data about your sql cache, memory usage etc.
It will help you diagnose the issue.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: I agree, the query and table is perfect, only way to speed it up is looking at system tools,especially cache...

Comment: Thanks for the help. MySQL told me via `ANALYZE` and `OPTIMIZE` that my structure was okay. I eventually ended up switching to MySQL spatial extensions (see my self-answer in the body of my post).

Answer (score 3):

<sub>**The content here is originally written by OP (Antilogical) as an edit to the question. I moved the answer portion from the question to here and made this a community wiki. @Antilogical, please ping me with comment if you want to post your own answer to gain reputation.**</sub>

### Well, I fixed it. Here's how:

I managed to reduce my query time from an initial 5s down to **0.6-0.7ms**. I stumbled upon this question, 'How to further optimize this MySQL table for a single Query' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548311/how-to-further-optimize-this-mysql-table-for-a-single-query). Which lead me to switch my table from InnoDB to MyISAM and use geospatial abstractions to represent my coordinate point.

Firstly, I switched from InnoDB to MyISAM which is better designed for MySQL spatial extensions.

```
ALTER TABLE `squares` ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Then, I created a geospatial column called `coordinate` which held a point object (which was simply just a concatenation of `ref_coord_lat` and `ref_coord_long`:

```
UPDATE `squares` SET `coordinate` = GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', `ref_coord_lat`,' ', `ref_coord_long`, ')'));
```

I the added a spatial index to `coordinate` - which dramatically increased the query performance. Initially while not using geospatial extensions, my query to select fields from my database was:

```
SELECT * FROM `squares` WHERE `ref_coord_lat` BETWEEN *somecoordinate* AND *somecoordinate* AND `ref_coord_long` BETWEEN *somecoordinate* and *somecoordinate*
```

What this query essentially does is imitates a bounding box by putting two limits/conditions of each axis (latitude & longitude). Note that `*` currently means all three fields of my database, I hadn't created `coordinate` yet. When I switched to using MySQL spatial extensions, I could now check against my new `coordinate` column by using a Minimum Bounding Rectangle with the function `MBRContains()` which is part of the MySQL geospatial extensions set.

```
SELECT * FROM `squares` WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText(POLYGON((*my four bounds now go here in lat,lon pairs*))), `coordinate`);
```

Notice how I'm still selecting all fields with `*`? You don't need to do that. The `coordinate` column is merely acting as a index to look values up against, so I now select everything but that column via this query below, which gives a significant speed increase over the one directly above.

```
SELECT `square_id`, `ref_coord_lat`, `ref_coord_long` FROM `squares` WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText(POLYGON((*my four bounds now go here in lat,lon pairs*))), `coordinate`);
```

There's been a multiple order of magnitude increase in speed:

- ~5s          - Time to query initial `squares` table (InnoDB, no indices)
- 1.40-1.45s   - Addition of two indices for `ref_coord_lat` & `ref_coord_long`
- 0.9s (900ms) - I then discovered that my constraint coordinates in my SELECT query had more than a dozen decimal places. I rounded them to 6 in my Javascript code (the same number of decimal places that my table stores coordinates in). This provided a decent speed increase.
- 0.5s (500ms) - As per @N.B.'s comment below, I increased the size of `inno_db_buffer_pool` from 16M to 256M.
- 45-50ms      - Switched to MyISAM engine, added a coordinate point column and added a spatial index
- 0.6-0.7ms    - I altered my query so that instead of selecting * columns, it selects all **but** my new `coordinate` column.

Database optimization? Done.

Answer (score 0):

While not very elegant, splitting into multiple tables (say one per 30 degrees of latitude) usually helps. Your query is such that it is obvious which tables contain the required points.

Also, use [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html) to investigate the problem.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of splitting the table, partitioning it might suffice. As you said, the EXPLAIN output would shed more light on the performance issue.