# Attempt to add geometry object to MySQL column based off other columns results in 'no rows affected'?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, spatial

This is actually a follow up to a prior question [I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202545/optimization-techniques-for-mysql-select-query-on-single-table-with-2-25m-rows) about how to improve `SELECT` query performance on a simple read-only database. Long story short, I have then found this [question & self-written-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548311/how-to-further-optimize-this-mysql-table-for-a-single-query) which can potentially solve my problem, but I'm having some trouble understanding one of the SQL statements presented on that page.

You can find additional details in my original question, but in summary, my table, which looks like this:

```
`squares` (
   `square_id` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
   `ref_coord_lat` double(8,6) NOT NULL,
   `ref_coord_long` double(9,6) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`square_id`),
   KEY `ref_coord_lat` (`ref_coord_lat`),
   KEY `ref_coord_long` (`ref_coord_long`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

was performing too slowly for my liking at 1.40-1.45 seconds per select query. The Q+A which I discovered recommended switching database from `InnoDB` to `MyISAM` to support MySQL's spatial extensions. I have now done this, and created a `NOT NULL`, `GEOMETRY POINT` column which I intend to populate with the latitude and longitude coordinates from `ref_coord_lat` and `ref_coord_long` respectively. The only thing is my query to achieve this does not work at all. And I have no idea why.

Here's the query that the answer used to populate a geometry column:

```
GeomFromText(CONCAT('LINESTRING(', start_ip, ' -1, ', end_ip, ' 1)'))
```

And here's my attempt at an adaptation for my purposes:

```
UPDATE `squares` SET `coordinate` = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', ref_coord_lat, ref_coord_long, ')'))
```

**Except this doesn't work.**

I'm not alerted to any SQL syntax errors by phpMyAdmin, in fact, all I get is a green 'completed' box which informs me that '0 rows were affected (Query took 0.00007 sec)'.

Any ideas why my query is not functioning correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I can see is that your coordinates have no spaces between them. Try this:

```
UPDATE `squares` SET `coordinate` = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', ref_coord_lat, ' ', ref_coord_long, ')'));
```