# Geospatial Java update prepared statement for MySQL not working

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, geospatial

I am trying to update a MySQL point type using the following prepared statement:

```
String selectQry = ("UPDATE at_group " +
              "SET grp_country=?, grp_state=?, grp_region=?, grp_district=?, " +
              "grp_name=?, grp_section=?, grp_sub_section=?, grp_archived=?, " +
              "grp_hall_geoPoint=?, grp_nas=? " +
              "WHERE grp_id=?;");
// Create a statement and execute the query on it
            String geo = ("POINT" + "(" + latitude + " " + longditude + ")");
            ps.setString(1, country);
            ps.setString(2, state);
            ps.setString(3, region);
            ps.setString(4, district);
            ps.setString(5, group);
            ps.setString(6, section);
            ps.setString(7, subSection);
            ps.setString(8, archiveDate);
            ps.setString(9, geo);
            ps.setString(10, nas);
            ps.setString(11, groupID);

            ps.executeUpdate();
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
SQLException in updateGroup: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

My input is -33.8 and 151.1

I followed the links (some of which are broken) and found the answer. I have posted the answer here for everyone's benefit. The Answer is:

```
    String selectQry = ("UPDATE at_group " +
              "SET grp_country=?, grp_state=?, grp_region=?, grp_district=?, " +
              "grp_name=?, grp_section=?, grp_sub_section=?, grp_archived=?, " +
              "grp_hall_geoPoint=PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', ?, ' ', ?, ')')), grp_nas=? " +
              "WHERE grp_id=?;");

// Create a statement and execute the query on it
            ps.setString(1, country);
            ps.setString(2, state);
            ps.setString(3, region);
            ps.setString(4, district);
            ps.setString(5, group);
            ps.setString(6, section);
            ps.setString(7, subSection);
            ps.setString(8, archiveDate);
            ps.setString(9, latitude);
            ps.setString(10, longditude);
            ps.setString(11, nas);
            ps.setString(12, groupID);

            ps.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207455/attempt-to-add-geometry-object-to-mysql-column-based-off-other-columns-results-i

Comment: I have a similar problem with an insert prepared statement. Can you point me to the right place. None of these do the trick.